# Neovim raises attempt to call field 'get_load_fts' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, neovim

After upgrading my neovim to 0.7.2 I get the following error

```
Error detected while processing BufWinEnter Autocommands for "*":
E5108: Error executing lua ...pack/paqs/start/LuaSnip/lua/luasnip/loaders/from_lua.lua:97: attempt to call field 'get_load_fts' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ...pack/paqs/start/LuaSnip/lua/luasnip/loaders/from_lua.lua:97: in function '_load_lazy_loaded'
        [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: attempt to call field '_load_lazy_loaded' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: attempt to call field '_load_lazy_loaded' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
```

Help on debugging very welcome!

Comment: Without some excerpts of your Neovim configuration (LSP, Packer, LuaSnip...), it is impossible to help you to debug this error.

Answer (score 1):

The error was due to conflicting versions of the plugin, installed via two different plugin managers.
Looking into the different paths in the runtime path (as found with :set rtp) I found different installs and checked their "freshness" with git log.
I removed the folders related to the no longer used plugin manager.

The neovim config files did not really help, rather some lua and git command, but yes, the remark of @Icheylus is usually correct.